# Flutter Package Publish Error says Package not compatible

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I published a package a while ago. But after new analysis, it gives the warning

> Package not compatible with SDK dart

It shows

> Analysis suggestions:
>
> Package not compatible with SDK dart
>
> because of import path [ola_like_country_picker]

I didn't get where this error is coming from.
Here is the link to the package https://pub.dev/packages/ola_like_country_picker#-analysis-tab-

Answer (score 1):

this is addressed in this [github issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39167)

TLDR

> When flutter did federated packages we talked about giving a package
>   two version numbers. This we resolved by creating two packages.
>
> Maybe there is two packages here:
>
> ```
> package:kernel_api which is a series of abstract classes. The major version is only bumped when the interfaces for parsing kernel
> ```
>
> files are broken.
>       package:kernel_parser which has a function that return concrete instance of an abstract class from package:kernel_api, which can be
>   used to parse kernel files. The major version of this package is
>   bumped whenever the kernel format breaks. In practice it might follow
>   the Dart SDK minor versions (for it's major version).
>
> This say you version the file-format in a package different from the
>   versioning of the interfaces used to read the file-format. If this
>   makes any sense :)
>   https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39167#issuecomment-547646728
>
> After some discussion about this in Aarhus between myself, @jonasfj,
>   @johnniwinther, @stefantsov, and @jensjoha , we're contemplating the
>   idea of moving the shared parts of analyzer and front_end into a new
>   package (which, notably, would not depend on kernel). That would
>   decouple the analyzer from kernel completely. It wouldn't directly
>   address this issue, but it would shrink its scope by decoupling the
>   decision of how to import kernel (and what version to import) from any
>   analyzer considerations. We could then consider options like:
>
> ```
> Flutter's transformer imports kernel directly from the SDK using a relative path
> Kernel increments their major version number with every SDK release, so that Flutter can be assured they have a compatible version
> ```
>
> of kernel by putting the proper version in the pubspec
>       Kernel publishes a separate package for each SDK release (e.g. kernel_2_7 to go with Dart 2.7)
>       Kernel is split into two packages, along the lines of @jonasfj's suggestion above.
>
> I'm currently awaiting feedback from the analyzer and front end teams
>   about the idea.
>   https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39167#issuecomment-547984002